# How to fix Grails export plugin's export excel file for more than 65000 rows?

Tags: grails

I am using Grails export plugin 1.1 to export the data from excel,pdf and csv.

When data is more than 65000 then csv and pdf is working fine but when I try exporting an excel its give the following error:

```
jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException: 
The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded 
   at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:1214) 
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1151) 
    at com.ibm.database.excel.WriteExcel.addLabel(WriteExcel.java:176) 
    at com.ibm.database.excel.WriteExcel.write(WriteExcel.java:76) 
    at com.ibm.database.excel.FileGenerator.generateExcel(FileGenerator.java:13) 
    at com.ibm.database.taxoreader.TaxonomyReader.main(TaxonomyReader.java:46)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe its a limitation of excel? Have you tried to add that many rows in excel manually?

Comment: Maybe split in more files?

Comment: it is the limitation of excel but how to solved this problem

Comment: so any other solution fro export excel  in grails